# Sleeping with my mouth slightly open causes my throat to dry out and ache a lot

Tags: personal-care

I have no clogged nose but still my mouth opens ever so slightly during the night and although I don't notice that I breathe through the mouth I have started to notice that my mouth is slightly open. Every morning my throat is very sore and lately my tongue too, which is a huge bother. What can I do to stop this? And does anyone else suffers from this problem: no clogged nose, still mouth slightly open?

Answer (score 3):

You may try  **anti snoring belts**.

These are meant for closing your mouth and permit very less air to enter, hence stop snoring. You don't have the snoring problem, but you can find the belt useful in keeping your mouth closed while sleeping. These are available with many modifications.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem myself sometimes, it does not leave my throat or tongue sore but it leaves them dry. the problem could be because you have bigger tonsils than normal (that is my reason for having the same problem). One way to stop the problem is but getting your tonsils removed. And your nose could still be clogged even if you can breathe through it, so before making the big decision of getting your tonsils removed you might want to try a netty pot.